# PHP open second Page when Table Row is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, dynamic

Out of the Database im fetching some Informations to create a table with the table rows and table data Elements (works!). With Javascript a EventListener to each Table Row is added with an onClick function which is triggered by a click inside a table row (works). Now I want to have an Overview Page, for example with some fields where the Information of the Table Row I clicked on, is inside. The Link to the other Page works also fine.

I'm stuck at the Problem how to get the Table Data exactly of the row I clicked on, because on the second Page I have to do another SQL query to fetch the Data from the Database.
I've read something about adding Parameter in the URL which (I think) leads to the problem, that I need one page for every single table row which has the Information parameter Im sending in the URL to use the GET Method to fetch it on the Overview Page.

Im not really sure whats the easiest and best way to do that.
I'm working (just) with PHP, Javascript, HTML and a MySQL Database.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can send a parameter to the second page

```
<tr data-id="1"></tr>
```

for example, see the above tr. you can use js to get the id and send it to the second page

second.php?id=1

then in second PHP file, you can get the id

```
$id = $_GET['id']
```

and use $id to fetch the data from database;

Comment: But that means, that my second file is named like e.g. your second page? So if I send for the data-id="2" the page needs to be second.php?id=2, is that right?

Comment: names after ? is URL get parameters. so there is one second.php file with different parameters.